# Setup windows doskey for echo > filename.txt

Tags: doskey

My goal is to setup `doskey` to imitate unix `touch` command as `touch filename.txt`

Without doskey I use `echo . > filename.txt` in the windows's command prompt

I successfully setup `doskey touch=echo $*` but I must use it as `touch > filename.txt`, I have tried to play around using `doskey touch=echo > $*`, this causes `echo` to be not recognized by the windows's command prompt.

Please help, thanks.

Please help,

Comment: I am trying to to the same. I will let you know if I have any success. I was trying with touch=type NUL > $*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
doskey touch=copy nul $* > nul
```

This bit of code exploits the copy command to make a new file. $* is the string you put after touch.

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Comment: " copy nul $* " is enough. I use " type nul > filename "  for touch ,but "type nul > $*" does not work. Do you know why?